# XMLPullParser returns only one element

Tags: kotlin, xml-parsing

I could not parse my XML file, it returns only one element instead of 4

Here's my XML file

```
<Quizzs>
<Quizz type="A">...</Quizz>
<Quizz type="B">...</Quizz>
<Quizz type="C">...</Quizz>
<Quizz type="D">...</Quizz>
</Quizzs>
```

It returns only the last one "D"

```
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            var eltName: String? = null

            when (eventType) {
                XmlPullParser.START_TAG -> {
                    eltName = parser.name

                    if ("Quizzs" == eltName) {
                        currentQuizz = Quizz()
                        quizz.add(currentQuizz)
                    } else if (currentQuizz != null) {
                        if ("Quizz" == eltName) {
                            currentQuizz.type = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "type")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            eventType = parser.next()
        }

        printPlayers(quizz)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `.add()` something to your `currentQuizz` for each `"Quizz"`. With `currentQuizz.type = ...` you just overwrite each previous `"Quizz"` with the current one, so you end up with only the last one, which is `D`.

I think you are confused by your own code. For the `"Quizzs"` tag you create a `Quizz()` object instead of a `QuizzList()` object or something similar. It is for the `"Quizz"` tag you should create a new `Quizz()` object each time. And then you should add that object to your `QuizzList`.